# BadPaddingException : Data must start with zero

Tags: java, string, encryption, arrays, public-key-encryption

I implemented data encryption/decryption with RSA. It works if I just encrypt/decrypt locally, however if I send my encrypted data I get BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero.

In order to send my data over network I need to change it from byte array to String (I'm sending it in a header) on the client side and then retrieve it and change it back to byte array on the server side.

Here's my code for local encryption/decryption (I'm using private key to encrypt and public key do decrypt):

```
// Encryption:
String message = "HELLO";
Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);  // privateKey has type java.security.PrivateKey
byte [] encryptedBytes = rsa.doFinal(message.getBytes());

// Decryption:
rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey); // type of publicKey: java.security.PublicKey
byte [] ciphertext = rsa.doFinal(encryptedBytes);

String decryptedString = new String(ciphertext, "UTF-8");
```

DecryptedString and message are the same and everything works fine.

Then I use the same code on the client side just for encryption plus I change ciphertext to a String using:

```
String encryptedString = new String(ciphertext, "UTF-8");
```

And on the server side I do:

```
String message = request.getHeader("Message"); 
byte [] msgBytes = message.getBytes("UTF-8");

Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte [] decryptedMsg = rsa.doFinal(msgBytes);

String decryptedString = new String(decryptedMsg, "UTF-8");
```

This doesn't work and I get BadPaddingException.

I have tried using different instance of cipher, e.g. "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" or "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" but this didn't help. I also tried converting Strings using BASE64 but then I get a different exception: IllegalBlockSizeException.

I know I probably do sth wrong with converting Strings into byte arrays and vice versa, but I just can't figure out the correct way of doing that. Please help!

Comment: Can you include the Exception stack trace?

Comment: Have you verified that the bytes you intend to send are the exact same as the bytes you attempt to decrypt on the client?

Comment: @agerrr, on a separate note, you should encrypt with public keys and decrypt with private keys.  Otherwise, everyone with your public key could decrypt your message.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just convert arbitrary binary data (the encrypted text) into a String.  If you want to send the data as text, you need to use some sort of binary -> text encoding like Base64.